# Use the old, XP style Alt+Tab in LXDE

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

How do I make the Alt+Tab in LXDE to show icons only, similar to Windows XP's Alt+Tab dialog?

This is how it looks now:

[image]

And this is the old XP style dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer here - http://urukrama.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/reverting-to-the-old-alt-tab-dialog-in-openbox-3-5/

You need to edit `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` (or `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` if you're on Lubuntu), and add `<dialog>icons</dialog>` to the Alt+Tab and Alt+Shift+Tab key-bindings, so they look like this:

```
<!-- Keybindings for window switching -->
<keybind key="A-Tab">
  <action name="NextWindow">
    <dialog>icons</dialog>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="A-S-Tab">
  <action name="PreviousWindow">
    <dialog>icons</dialog>
  </action>
</keybind>
```